# WSO2-ESB: SOAP Mediator from wsdl

Tags: wso2, esb

I have seen some of the SOAP- Example- Mediators. I have not found a transformation based on the endpoint-WSDL.

I want to send some nested named array in json or POX and that data should go into a complete namespaced headered (username, password) SOAP-Request based on the names.

All the examples I have found had either a very simple wsdl or the namespaces were static in the XSL-Transformation.

It should be possible to do that, as I see in for example php-NuSOAP. You feed it with a wsdl-endpoint, the operation you want to execute and the parameter-array, and it calls the Webservice.

I am looking for a solution which is not too much hardcoded for every single service, so the proxy still works when the wsdl changes and Server Clients get changed.

As far as I understand the payload factory mediator in (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12969814/2277620) you would have to hardcode the soap-format in the mediator.

If WSO2 is the wrong tool for that I'd like to have a hint which tool could help.

Thanks in advance!

Marco.

Answer (score 1):

For my understanding, you want to have a proxy, but it's backend service/wsdl may vary..
What , you can do is, you can save the wsdl (dynamic wsdl)in registry and point that in your proxy. whenever you edit the wsdl, proxy will automatically adopt to that..But the request, which you  send to your backend should follow the wsdl definitions..It is totally client side responsibility..

Comment: When I follow example 440 (synapse), then the content of the Soap-Message is only enriched with the hard-coded namespace from the xsl. I think all those namespaces could come from the wsdl. But that seems not easy or not possible with xslt-mediator.